# MVC with Kendo treeview - remote data JSON or XML

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, treeview, kendo-ui

I'm trying to create a Kendo TreeView that gets populated from my controller (`PropertyController`).

The part I'm stuck at is how to format my data in the controller. How could I create a TreeView three items deep and pass that to my view to be displayed in the TreeView?

```
@(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
    .Name("treeview")
    .Events(events => events
        .DragStart("PartnershipPage.OnDragStart")
        .Drop("PartnershipPage.OnDrop")
        .DragEnd("PartnershipPage.OnDragEnd")
    )
    .HighlightPath(true)
    .DragAndDrop(true)
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Read(read => read
            .Action("Index","Tree")
        )
    )
)
```

I've included the controller to see if I'm doing it correctly. All that is happening so far is the JSON is being displayed on the screen as text.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var org = new Entities();
    var eList = new List<Entity>();

    var entity1 = new Entity
    {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "LLC-A",
        parentId = 0
    };
    eList.Add(entity1);

    var entity2 = new Entity
    {
        Id = 2,
        Name = "LLC-B",
        parentId = 0
    };
    eList.Add(entity2);

    var entity3 = new Entity
    {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "LLC-C",
        parentId = 2
    };
    eList.Add(entity3);

    var entity4 = new Entity
    {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "LLC-D",
        parentId = 2
    };
    eList.Add(entity4);

    org.Entity = eList;

    var test = from x in org.Entity
               where (x.Name != null)
               select new
               {
                   Id = x.Id,
                   Name = x.Name,
                   parentId = x.parentId
               };
    ;

    return Json(test, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From: [Kendo Site](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/wrappers/aspnet-mvc/Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent/TreeViewBuilder)

```
<%= Html.Kendo().TreeView()
    .Name("TreeView")
    .BindTo(Model, mapping => mapping
        .For<Customer>(binding => binding
            // The "child" items will be bound to the the "Orders" property
            .Children(c => c.Orders)
            // Map "Customer" properties to TreeViewItem properties
            .ItemDataBound((item, c) => item.Text = c.ContactName)
        )
        .For<Order>(binding => binding
            // "Orders" do not have child objects so return "null"
            .Children(o => null)
            // Map "Order" properties to TreeViewItem properties
            .ItemDataBound((item, o) => item.Text = o.OrderID.ToString())
        )
    )
%>
```

Comment: How would this look from the controller / model side?

Answer (score 2):

You could put your entities into a list called for example, "`myEntities`" and return that from the controller to the view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var ents = getMyEntities(); // some method you have to return the list of your entities
    return ents;
}
```

Then in your view, you can loop through all the entities in your Model:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
    .Name("TreeView")
    .Items(treeview =>
    {
        foreach (var entity in Model)
        {
            var entityName = entity.Name;
            var children = entity.Children;
            
            treeview.Add()
                .Text(entityName)
                .Expanded(false)
                .Items(branch =>
                {
                    if (children != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var child in children)
                        {
                            branch.Add().Text(child);
                        }
                     }
                });
        }
    })
)
```

I used children because I found it easier to use than parent and so I would change my entities to something like this:

```
var entity4 = new Entity
{
    Id = 1,
    Name = "LLC-D",
    Children = <list of children names ... >
};
```

You can see how I did mine here: [Populate KendoUI Treeview with RavenDB Documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13848228/populate-kendoui-treeview-with-ravendb-documents/13879988#13879988)

Hope this helps.

---

Edit in response to: How can I display children of children?

---

I ran into the same problem as you describe (displaying children of children). Here is how I did it after I had the problem of displaying children of children.

Using Entity Framework, here is the DB context class:

```
public class EntityDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MyEntity> Entities { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public JsonResult EntitiesForTreeView(int? id)
{
    // Here I am using EntityFramework
    var entitiesContext = new EntityDBContext();
    var myEntity= from e in entitiesContext.Entities
                  where (id.HasValue ? e.Parent == id : e.Parent == null)
                  select new
                  {
                      id = e.Id,
                      Name = e.Name,
                      hasChildren = e.Id
                  };
                  
    return Json(myEntity, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And the View:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
    .Name("treeview")
    .DataTextField("Name")
    .LoadOnDemand(true)
    .HighlightPath(true)
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Read(read => read
            .Action("EntitiesForTreeView", "SiteMap")
        )
    )
    .Checkboxes(true)
)
```

Hope this helps. Sorry if there is something stupid - I've only been doing web development for 3 months so unmark as answer if needed. Let me know if I can help further.

PS: I should mention that after implementing the solution I have shown above, I noticed that the nodes on my tree all have the "+" sign... regardless of whether or not they have any children. If you know how to fix this, please let me know :)

Comment: Rich, if I go that route, how could I show children of children?