# How update local data of DataSource without use read() function KendoUI

Tags: html, telerik, kendo-ui

I need update the local data of DataSource but without use de read() function. I use the read() function but this function slows the site.

Comment: Did you try using the DataSource API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass a list of your objects to the view and then iterate through them.
I did this for my treeview.

Have a look at my post: [Populate KendoUi Treeview with RavenDB documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13848228/populate-kendoui-treeview-with-ravendb-documents/13879988#13879988)

Hopefully it will help you :)

If you give us some more information, eg: What control are you using?

Then maybe we can help further.

Comment: I need use for update a Chart of Dataviz. You use a ASP.net MVC but I need for HTML. Thank's....